# Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am learning Blazor and C# (new to both) and am playing with a pet project of mine.

For that project, I have written a `Project.cs` file located in the `Data` directory of the structure that was created following [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/create) tutorial.

At some point, I need a dictionnary data structure that I try to create like this within a class :

```
namespace MyApp.Data;

public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> openWith =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no
    // duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
    openWith.Add("txt", "notepad.exe");
    openWith.Add("bmp", "paint.exe");
    openWith.Add("dib", "paint.exe");
    openWith.Add("rtf", "wordpad.exe");
}
```

But I receive the error `Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration` whereas I took the lines from Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) directly

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps it could be made clearer in the example in the documentation but those lines are intended to appear *inside* a method.

Comment: You are trying to call `openWith.Add` outside of a method. They shoud belong to some method's body. Place them inside of the `Project` ctor and it will compile.

Comment: Note that it is possible to declare and initialize the dictionary outside of a method, by using collection initializer syntax: `Dictionary<string, string> openWith = new() { { "txt", "notepad.exe" }, { "bmp", "paint.exe" }, ... };`

Comment: Unless you're working with c# 10 (which is currently the latest c# version), File Scoped Namespaces are not supported. Also, you're code is missing `}` at the end of the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you cant' run any code  inside of the class.  You can move your code inside of the constructor or inside of a special method  or you can init property directly  using {}.

```
public class Project
{
        Dictionary<string, string> openWith =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

   public Project()
    {

    openWith.Add("txt", "notepad.exe");
    openWith.Add("bmp", "paint.exe");
    openWith.Add("dib", "paint.exe");
    openWith.Add("rtf", "wordpad.exe");

    }
}
```